# $this is overwritten on quick succession of clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a series of `div` tags with anchors that, when clicked, slide a panel down that's populated with AJAX. The code looks something like this:

```
        $('.details').click(function(e) {

            $this = $(this).parents('.container');
            var id = $this.data('id');

            $(this).slideToggle('slow', function() {
                if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                    $.ajax({ 
                        type: 'POST', 
                        url: '/method', 
                        data: { id: id }, 
                        timeout: 5000
                    }).done(function(result){

                        console.log('Done was fired.');
                        console.log($this);

                        // This is my headache:
                        // Using $this here to do some stuff

                    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log('Fail was fired.');
                        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    });
```

If I click on two links quickly, the first begins, then before it finishes, the second begins, overwriting this line: `$this = $(this).parents('.container');`, which ultimately gives the impression the ajax never finishes. How do I ensure I have access to the correct `$this`? Should I continue to query the DOM, or use some kind of variable, variable name?

Comment: The `$this` you are referencing is in global scope.  Simply prefix with `var ` in declaration

Comment: You're missing a `var` in front of `$this` which is causing it to become a global variable.

Comment: Unforgivable. Thanks, guys.

Comment: To avoid this in development add `'use strict';` to the top level scope of your JS file and it will complain about using globals unexpectedly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is a global variable!

```
    $('.details').click(function(e) {

        $this = $(this).parents('.container');
    ^^^    
   No var
```

Add the `var` so it will have local scope and than it will not be overwritten

```
    $('.details').click(function(e) {

        var $this = $(this).parents('.container');
        ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `$this` a local variable in the function instead of a global variable in the page:

```
var $this = $(this).parents('.container');
```

By declaring the variable locally in the function, each call to the function gets its own variable. When the callback function for the AJAX call uses the variable, it uses the local variable that is captured in the closure for the callback function, not a global variable.